# How to have a SoundCloud Follow button on my website?

Tags: soundcloud, vimeo, vimeo-api

Is there a way to embed a SoundCloud Follow button on my website so users can Follow the page/channel from the website it self?

Is it possible to have something similar with Vimeo too?

Comment: similar to SoundCloud - here the vimeo badge, you have to change the url: http://vimeo.com/tools/widget/blogbadge

Comment: Hi, this just re-direct the users to my Vimeo page right? What I want is a way to let users to 'Follow' my Vimeo page from my site it self.

Comment: Not directly, but using their api you can build it. http://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/me#/followers

Answer (score 1):

Looks like SoundCloud opened up functionality for "following" via their [API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#follow)

Unfortunately, for the time being, they have closed off new apps from [registering](https://soundcloud.com/you/apps/new) with their API... not sure when/if that will open back up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @davidpm4 - got it working with the updated [API here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#follow)

Here is the auth. code for popup:

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.3.0.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  redirect_uri: 'http://example.com/callback'
});

// initiate auth popup
SC.connect().then(function() {
  return SC.get('/me');
}).then(function(me) {
  alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
});
</script>
```

This is for the callback:

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.3.0.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  redirect_uri: 'http://example.com/callback'
});

SC.connect().then(function() {
  // Follow user with ID 3207
  SC.put('/me/followings/3207').then(function(){
    // Unfollow the same user
    SC.delete('/me/followings/3207');
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

For SoundCloud, you can customise an icon here – https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed

Comment: Hi, this just re-direct the users to my SoundCloud page right? What I want is a way to let users to 'Follow' my SoundCloud page from my site it self.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not offer something like that at this time.

Comment: @gryzzly - offer it please.

Comment: With the OP's comment, this answer is superfluos and imprecise. I down voted it.